# VBA: Userform initialize method not being hit when userform initializes

Tags: vba, module, listbox, initialization, userform

My module code calling the userform:

```
PreInfo.Show
```

My userform code:

```
Public Sub PreInfo_Initialize()
Dim Invoice, Name, Model, Crank, MyValue1, StrokeL As Variant
'Dim ListBox1 As ListBox
Dim c As Range
Dim oneControl As Object

'Empty Text Boxes and Set Focus
For Each oneControl In PreInfo.Controls
Select Case TypeName(oneControl)
Case "TextBox"
    oneControl.Text = vbNullString
'Case "ListBox"
    'oneControl.AddItem "Test"
End Select
Next oneControl

With lbTest
    .AddItem Item:="2 Cylinders" '3 different syntax used as test to isolate issue
    .AddItem "3 Cylinders"
    .AddItem ("5 Cylinders")
End With

Invoice.TextBox.SetFocus 'Activate?

End Sub
```

My module code does not trigger my userform initialize sub, therefore nothing in that sub runs. I cannot figure out why this is happening. I would greatly appreciate any help!

When this code runs, userform pops up, however none of the listbox items are added

Comment: Have you previously used `UserForm.hide`?

Comment: I use userform.hide when the user clicks the "continue" button on the userform, which closes the userform and prints the userform inputs into a worksheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured it out. Long story short, my Module needed the following code:

```
Userform.Userform_Activate 'THIS IS THE NEW CODE
Userform.Show 'existing code, unchanged
```

which signals the userform to activate before it is open (calling "initialize", then showing the userform for the user to alter).

Userform.Show SHOULD cue this activation sub to run, however mine was not for whatever reason. This fixes the issue until I determine why Userform.Userform_Activate was not called like it should have been.

Answer (score 7):

Userform_Initialize event is triggered by a line like this called in a module:

```
Load Userform1
```

In order for it to be triggered again, you'll need to unload the userform (not simply hide it). This can be done either after the load call within the module:

```
Unload Userform1
```

Or anywhere within the Userform's code:

```
Unload Me
```

Notice that the events **Initialize** and **QueryClose** will be triggered by the **Unload** call as well (**QueryClose** is also triggered when the close button on the top right corner is pressed), so I really recommend you refrain from using **Initialize**. Instead, After the **Load** call, add the initialize code within the same module (or create a separate sub if it'll be called from multiple places).

```
Sub LoadThatUserform
    Load Preinfo
    'All textboxes are loaded with their value set to vbnullstring, _
         unless you specified otherwise in the Properties box.
    With ThatUserform.lbTest
    'Answering this test
        .AddItem Item:="2 Cylinders" 'Here you used the parameter name. _
              It's entirely optional, which is why the one below _
              also works. It's necessary, however, if you wanna skip _
              an optional parameter on a procedure call.
        .AddItem "3 Cylinders"
        .AddItem ("5 Cylinders") 'This will theoretically create a _
              run-time error: a procedure call either outside of a Call _
              statement or not setting a value to a variable or property _
              doesn't require parentheses.
    End With
    'After loading, show the form
    Preinfo.Show
    'Showing, if not as modeless, stops code execution for the user _
          to make changes to the form. Once he presses a button _
          or whatever, and the form is hidden, code will resume. _
          After you grab every form data you need, just call Unload.
    Unload Preinfo
End Sub
```

Last but not least, if you're running a **Modeless** form (let's code run in the background while showing), you'll need to use the **Activate** event for the  code to run. The event sequence is:

- **Userform_Initialize**, after **Load Userform**
- **Userform_Activate**, after **Userform.Show**
- **Userform_QueryClose**, after **Unload Userform**, pressing the closing "X" or terminating via closing Excel/Task Manager
- **Userform_Terminate**, when it's really gonna end (though I have no clue how this is used).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and found a very simple solution.

In your case, instead of using

```
Public Sub PreInfo_Initialize()
```

use

```
Public Sub UserForm_Initialize()
```

Answer (score 1):

> I use userform.hide when the user clicks the "continue" button on the userform, which closes the userform and prints the userform inputs into a worksheet

What is happenening is that your userform is never unloaded from memory. `Hide` only removes it from view.

This means that it is only initialized the first time you run the userform within that Excel instance.

You can prevent this by using

```
unload me
```

or

```
End
```

instead of `UserForm.Hide` depending on your other code. You could also potentially use the `UserForm_Activate` method instead of `UserForm_Initialize` method.

---

To populate the ListBox, use:

```
lbTest.AddItem "3 Cylinders"
```

etc outside the `With` statement.

Comment: Changed syntax to:

    unload me

The userform comes up, however the ListBox still does not populate.

Comment: @AlexBarrie I added code which solves that problem. If the above code doesn't work, put a breakpoint there and see if your code even gets into this method.

Comment: Altered the code (same result). Added break point at the code (program continues past that point without triggering the breakpoint). It's as if the userform.show works, however doesn't trigger the userform_activate sub.

Comment: @AlexBarrie and just to be clear, you have this code in the code associated with your UserForm?

Comment: Yes, this project has one module and two userforms (this trouble one being the first one. the second is only textbox's and works as needed). Userform.show is one of the first lines in my module, the rest of the code above is inside the userform, inside the userform_activate() sub. it is a public sub.

Comment: I have figured it out. the syntax "Userform.Userform_Activate" needs to be added above "Userform.Show" in order to direct focus to it before allowing user inputs to the form. Thank you for helping, enderland.

Comment: @AlexBarrie don't call Userform.Userform_Activate" from your code, this is called automatically when you activate the userform (assuming the code is contained within the code for the UserForm).

Comment: It wasnt calling it, though. Userform_Initialize (or activate) never got called after my module hit "Userform.Show". I added the above code and now my ListBox populates correctly when the userform is opened.

Comment: @AlexBarrie, what sub did you place the activate in your module?

Answer (score 1):

you have to keep syntax UserForm_Initialize() to make it happen

Cheers

Comment: I feel like such an idiot! This was the problem for me. I was using TestForm_Initialize() for a form named TestForm. Changed it to UserForm_Initialize() and it works as expected.